# How to reduce run time in my python code?

Tags: python, numpy, runtime, nested-for-loop

I am currently working on a project that requires me to run a complete python code base. For research purpose, I need to run the code as fast as possible. Yet I am fairly new to programming and have no idea how to reduce run time. So I hope someone can help me on that. Any advice would be appreciated. Here's part of my code base, which used a lot of nested for loops, so it might significantly increase run time.

```
 def a_j(r, a, A): # the Claussius-Mossotti factor, determined by a symmetric (3 × 3) matrix such that (A_i)^T = A_i
        alph = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],complex)
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                alph[i,j] = (r * a * A[i,j])
        return alph

    def W_ext(x, k, rho, alpha, A): # particle–particle interaction term
        n = x.shape[0] # the number of x vextors 
        result = np.zeros([3*n,3*n],complex)
        u = np.zeros((n, 3)) # u = x - x' 
        
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i != j:
                    u[i] = x[i] - x[j]
                    block_result = a_j(rho[i], alpha, A) * G((u[i]), k) * a_j(rho[j], alpha, A) 
                    for m in range(3):
                        for l in range(3):
                            result[3*i + m, 3*j + l] = block_result[m,l]
        return result.imag
    
    def A_ext(rho, a, A): # single-particle term
        n = rho.shape[0]
        result = np.zeros([3*n,3*n],complex)
        
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i == j:
                    block_result = a_j(rho[i], a, A).imag
                    for m in range(3):
                        for l in range(3):
                            result[3*i + m, 3*j + l] = block_result[m,l]
        return result # (3 x 3) matrix
    
    def P_ext(e, A, W, omega):
        eT = np.matrix.getH(e)
        mm1 = np.matmul(A, e)
        mm2 = np.matmul(W, e)
        extinction = (np.dot(eT, mm1) + np.dot(eT, mm2)) * (omega/2.0)
        return extinction
    
    #ABSORPTION
    
    def W_abs(x, k, rho, alpha, A, chi): # particle–particle interaction term
        n = x.shape[0] 
        result = np.zeros([3*n,3*n],complex)
        u = np.zeros((n, 3)) 
        
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i != j:
                    u[i] = x[i] - x[j]
                    block_result = np.matrix.getH(a_j(rho[i], alpha, A)) * (1.0 / np.conjugate(chi)).imag * a_j(rho[i], alpha, A) * G((u[i]), k) * a_j(rho[j], alpha, A) 
                    for m in range(3):
                        for l in range(3):
                            result[3*i + m, 3*j + l] = block_result[m,l]        
           
        return 2.0 * result.real  # (3 x 3) matrix

    def A_abs(rho, a, A, chi): # single-particle term
        n = rho.shape[0]
        result = np.zeros([3*n,3*n],complex)
        
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i == j:
                    block_result = np.matrix.getH(a_j(rho[i], a, A)) * (1.0 / np.conjugate(chi)).imag * a_j(rho[i], a, A)
                    for m in range(3):
                        for l in range(3):
                            result[3*i + m, 3*j + l] = block_result[m,l]
        return result # (3 x 3) matrix
```

Comment: what is this naming convention O.O

Comment: One example:    Where you have a nested loop over i and j, with "if(i==j)" in the body, just drop the inner loop and use "i" where "j" currently appears.   Similarly in some of the other def's.

Comment: What is `a_j`? nested `for` loops will always increase runtime.  The first 2 loops in themselves account for `O(n^2)` time complexity. Add onto that whatever the cost of calling `a_j` is.

Comment: Python is not the way to go if you want really good performance, especially for loops which have a lot of overhead compared to something made with native code. You would need to utilize Python libraries that are compiled binaries to do this instead, or make your own library, or use Cython or something similar to combine high-performance C code with Python's flexibility.

Comment: I'm not a `numpy` expert, but I think a large part of the point of using `np.array` as you're trying to do is to take the types of operations you're doing in Python `for` loops and push them into `numpy` calls that run as compiled C rather than in the Python interpreter.  I suggest spending some time with the numpy docs to see if there are functions that would do the equivalent of what you're currently doing in your own code.